# Why doesn't CameraX.bindToLifecycle support three cases in 1.0.0-alpha05?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm learning CameraX API, and CameraXBasic is a office sample code.

The Code A is based [CameraFragment.kt](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt)

I add `videoCaptureConfig`, and bind it to lifecycle using  `CameraX.bindToLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner, preview, imageCapture,videoCapture).`

But I get the following error, why?

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No supported surface combination is found for camera device - Id : 0.  May be attempting to bind too many use cases.*

**Code A**

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private fun bindCameraUseCases() {

    // Get screen metrics used to setup camera for full screen resolution
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { viewFinder.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
    val screenAspectRatio = Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)

    // Set up the view finder use case to display camera preview
    val viewFinderConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        // We request aspect ratio but no resolution to let CameraX optimize our use cases
        setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
        // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
        // during the lifecycle of this use case
        setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
    }.build()

    // Use the auto-fit preview builder to automatically handle size and orientation changes
    preview = AutoFitPreviewBuilder.build(viewFinderConfig, viewFinder)


    // Set up the capture use case to allow users to take photos
    val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
        // We request aspect ratio but no resolution to match preview config but letting
        // CameraX optimize for whatever specific resolution best fits requested capture mode
        setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
        // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
        // during the lifecycle of this use case
        setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
    }.build()

    imageCapture = ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig)


    // Create a configuration object for the video use case
    val videoCaptureConfig = VideoCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
        setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
        setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
    }.build()
    videoCapture = VideoCapture(videoCaptureConfig)


    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner, preview, imageCapture,videoCapture)
}
```

Comment: Try a different resolution, it should support *upto 3*

Comment: @HelloCW Does it work if you unbind the image use case before binding the video one? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to unbind all use cases before to switch to video ( I noticed some crash with old phones when unbinding only the imageCapture use case):

```
// Listener for button photo
btnPhoto.setOnClickListener( v -> bindCameraUseCases(0));
// Listener for button video
btnVideo.setOnClickListener( v -> bindCameraUseCases(1));
```

Example with camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha06" (JAVA)

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private void bindCameraUseCases(int captureMode) {
    CameraX.unbindAll();

    AspectRatio screenAspectRatio = AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3;

    // Set up the preview use case to display camera preview
    PreviewConfig.Builder previewConfigBuilder = new PreviewConfig.Builder();
    previewConfigBuilder.setLensFacing(lensFacing);
    previewConfigBuilder.setTargetRotation(viewFinder.getDisplay().getRotation());
    previewConfigBuilder.setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio);
    Preview preview = new Preview(previewConfigBuilder.build());

    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(previewOutput -> {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) viewFinder.getParent();
        parent.removeView(viewFinder);
        parent.addView(viewFinder,0);
        viewFinder.setSurfaceTexture(previewOutput.getSurfaceTexture());
    });

    if(captureMode == 0){ // IMAGE
        videoCapture = null;
        // Set up the capture use case to allow users to take photos
        ImageCaptureConfig.Builder imageCaptureConfigBuilder = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder();
        imageCaptureConfigBuilder.setLensFacing(lensFacing);
        imageCaptureConfigBuilder.setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY);
        imageCaptureConfigBuilder.setTargetRotation(viewFinder.getDisplay().getRotation());
        imageCapture = new ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfigBuilder.build());

        // Apply declared configs to CameraX using the same lifecycle owner
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture);
    }else{ // VIDEO
        imageCapture = null;
        // Set up the video capture use case to allow users to take videos
        VideoCaptureConfig.Builder videoCaptureConfigBuilder = new VideoCaptureConfig.Builder();
        videoCaptureConfigBuilder.setLensFacing(lensFacing);
        videoCaptureConfigBuilder.setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio);
        videoCaptureConfigBuilder.setTargetRotation(viewFinder.getDisplay().getRotation());
        videoCapture = new VideoCapture(videoCaptureConfigBuilder.build());

        // Apply declared configs to CameraX using the same lifecycle owner
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, videoCapture);
    }
}
```

Example with camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha07" (JAVA)

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private void bindCameraUseCases(int captureMode) {
    if(cameraProvider != null) cameraProvider.unbindAll();

    // Set up the preview use case to display camera preview
    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
            .setTargetRotation(previewView.getDisplay().getRotation())
            .build();

    preview.setPreviewSurfaceProvider(previewView.getPreviewSurfaceProvider());

    if(captureMode == 0){ // IMAGE
        videoCapture = null;
        // Set up the capture use case to allow users to take photos
        imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                .setTargetRotation(previewView.getDisplay().getRotation())
                .build();

        // Apply declared configs using the same lifecycle owner
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this,cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture);
    }else{ // VIDEO
        imageCapture = null;
        // Set up the video capture use case to allow users to take videos
        VideoCaptureConfig.Builder videoCaptureConfigBuilder = new VideoCaptureConfig.Builder();
        videoCaptureConfigBuilder.setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3);
        videoCaptureConfigBuilder.setTargetRotation(previewView.getDisplay().getRotation());
        videoCapture = new VideoCapture(videoCaptureConfigBuilder.getUseCaseConfig());

        // Apply declared configs using the same lifecycle owner
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector,preview, videoCapture);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that I can't bind both  image capture mode and  video capture mode simultaneous?

Comment: Yes, at least for the moment. The video use case is currently marked as hidden in the API and is in a very preliminary state and subject to change. It seems the team working on cameraX is going to work on the video beginning of 2020. The best would be to wait an official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add too many use cases to the same camera session. You can check this [github-issue](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues/38) about that. For understand limitations of camera sessions you can check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html?source=post_page---------------------------#createCaptureSession(android.hardware.camera2.params.SessionConfiguration)).

Comment: Thanks! How can I fix the problems?

Comment: I think you must bind like in [sample](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L322). If you want to bind video capture use case you must first unbind image capture and bind video capture. Like camera applications, image capture mode, video capture mode seperatly.